# How long does it take to charge Thresh's Flay?

Tags: league-of-legends

[Thresh's Flay (E)](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Thresh#Flay) has a usefull passive:

> Thresh's basic attacks deal bonus magic damage on each hit. This value is equal to the total number of Souls collected, plus a percentage of his attack damage based on the amount of time since his last attack.

**When does the charging start?**

**How long does it take the passive to be fully charged?**

**Does the charging scale with the attackspeed?** (more AS = less chargetime?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Recharging starts roughly 0.5 seconds after your last triggering of the passive and it takes 10 seconds to reach its full damage. **This charging time cannot be reduced by any stat**.

Every hit will deal your amount of souls as bonus damage (regardless of charge time).

After 5 seconds you will deal half the bonus damage you'd deal at max charge + your souls and after 10 seconds you will deal the bonus damage that's displayed on the tooltip.

Note that Attacks against structures and wards will **not** reset your counter since it's not triggering the passive.

The bonus damage scales off your Total AD and your collected souls and it's a magic-damage on-hit effect which means that it will not benefit from spellvamp or lifesteal.

Comment: does the charging scale with the attackspeed? (more AS = less chargetime?)

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW it's in the answer: The charge time cannot be reduced by any stat. I highlighted it.

Comment: "Every hit will deal your amount of souls as bonus damage" - This seems to clash with your initial statement about when the charging starts.  Given that max attack speed leaves only 0.4s between attacks, only one of those statements can be true.  Perhaps the charging starts somewhat earlier than 0.5s?

Comment: The bonusdamage from the souls is a on-hit effect that requires no charging. The LoL wiki also states that he will get only 0.25% AS increase per 1% AS on items(I will test this myself once I get home,I've never heard of that before but it would mean that he doesn't get to 0.4 attacks/second).

Comment: @gruntswilldie His attack animation windup increases slower.  This means that AS doesn't allow him to kite as well as most champs, but doesn't affect his full-rate standing still attack speed.

Answer (score 2):

Thresh has a particle effect.

As Flay passively charges up its bonus AA damage, his hook starts to glow brighter. It also has a sound effect that triggers when it reaches **full charge (which takes 10 seconds)**.

> "(...) plus a percentage of his attack damage based on the amount of time since his last attack."

So it starts charging **after your last auto-attack**.

**No the charging does not scale with Attack Speed.**

If you want to see for yourself, take Thresh into a custom game and put a point into Flay.

Comment: i edited my question for another point